# Help me to fix reflection problem

Tags: rigging, bones, reflection

[image]

My helmet reflection is distorted when I move a bone head. I don't know how to solve is

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n41ku7dmLktpH3lJzI8Bnjf__MsHi-nB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: hello, it is not clear, do you mean that the object is deformed? Please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: sorry, i added link to description

Comment: when i open your file the helmet isn't even on the shoulders...just laying around. So maybe you should upload a version which looks like your screenshot....

Answer (score 0):

Your mesh is high-poly, which will make rigging and animations more complicated imho, but what you could do is join the helmet to the rest of the body (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>), remove its vertices from all groups and assign them to the vertex group called spine.006 which is controlled by the head bone:

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks you very much